# All my android app get force close in AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have a problem in AVD and eclipse.

I make new android app  and when I try to run it on AVD or my android device but I get force close .

Manifest file :

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.azkar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


       <activity android:name="com.your.package.YourLauncherActivity"      
        android:name=".main"
        android:lable="@string/app_name">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

        </intent-filter>
 </activity>  

     </application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: Post your logcat error trace.

Comment: What is your error? Show your logcat.

Comment: Is this your manifest same in your project?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using this manifest file without any change then you need to change here from

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.YourLauncherActivity"      
    android:name=".main"
    android:lable="@string/app_name">

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

to

```
<activity android:name="com.example.azkar.YourLauncherActivity"      
    android:name=".main"
    android:lable="@string/app_name">

 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.YourLauncherActivity"
```

with this:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.azkar.YourLauncherActivity"
```

Comment: i change it to >  <activity android:name="com.example.azkar.YourLauncherActivity">      but still force close

Answer (score 0):

below line  makes problem to you"

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.YourLauncherActivity"
```

make sure with your package and activity name:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.azkar.YourLauncherActivity"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.YourLauncherActivity"
```

To

```
<activity android:name="com.example.azkar.YourLauncherActivity"
```